# Foreach SQLDataReader

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have an page that list rows from my DB table, with User Name and an CheckBox.
I need an function that send email to User when CheckBox.checked is true, but don't show Email in my page.
I have these mothods:

```
public class ListRequest
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}

public List<ListRequest> PreencheValores(SqlDataReader reader)
{
    var lista = new List<ListRequest>();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        var listRequest = new ListRequest();
        listRequest.UserName = reader["User"].ToString();
        listRequest.Email = reader["Email"].ToString();
        lista.Add(listRequest);
    }
    return lista;
}

public List<ListRequest> ConsultarRequest()
{
    var lstRetorno = new List<ListRequest>();
    using (objConexao = new SqlConnection(strStringConexao))
    {
        using (objCommand = new SqlCommand(strSelectPorID, objConexao))
        {
            try
            {
                objConexao.Open();
                objCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", dm3);

                var objDataReader = objCommand.ExecuteReader();
                if (objDataReader.HasRows)
                    lstRetorno = PreencheValores(objDataReader);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                objConexao.Close();
            }
        }
    }
    return lstRetorno;
}
```

How I can make foreach for this?? I need get all string Email to this list but don't show Email in my page.
now I use foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView.Rows) to get name when CheckBox.cheked is true.
I'm clear in question?
Tks!

Comment: so it looks like you have code to obtain the email address/es for a user-name; can't you just *call that method*, and iterate over the returned list? where are you stuck?

Comment: One option is to insert a hidden field with the email value, and then you get the hidden field control in the same way you did with the checkbox. If you want to hide the email from hidden fields, consider cache the bound collection and insert an identifier into the hidden field.

Comment: @MarcGravell I have an method to event Send (an Button in my page). in this method I need an foreach to get each email to User Name when is Checked. How I said, I make an foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView.Rows), but it not get Email because Email not shows in my GridView. How I make an foreach to my list?

Comment: @gustavodidomenico Tks for your answer! I created an asp:HiddenField to Email and works correctly!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do something with each row in objDataReader, use

```
While objDataReader.Read()
    'do something
End While
```